# Finding the sum of a 5x5 array

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with my code. I am trying to find the sum of this 5x5 array, but it keeps giving me a total of 0. When I use a 2x2 array it works, but it won't work for a 5x5. Can anyone please help?

```
import java.util.*;

public class QuestionOne
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0, num4=0, num5=0;
    int [][] numArray = new int [5][5];
    int average =0, totalRow=0;
    int highestVal=0, lowestVal=0;

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
      num1 = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
      num4 =rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
      for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
      {
        num2 = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
        num5 = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
      }
      num3 = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
      System.out.println(num1+" " +num2+" " +num3 +" " +num4 +" " +num5);
    }

    //Sum all values    
    int total;
    total =0;
    for (int row = 0; row < numArray.length; row++)
    {
      for (int col = 0; col < numArray[row].length; col++)
      {
        total = total + numArray[row][col];
      }
    }

    System.out.println("The total is " + total);
//System.out.println(numArray.length);
```

Comment: You haven't made use of `numArray`, unless you actually started calculating the total. And if you don't store anything there, shouldn't it default to 0?

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: You never put any values into the array. What exactly do you expect to be summing when there's nothing there to sum? The code that should be populating the array never touches the array.

Comment: I have a random number generating that is inputting random values from 1-1000 @KenWhite

Comment: Yes, you do generate them. But you **never store those values in the array**. You generate them and throw them away. Look at how you're summing the array. See how you access a specific element? Where in the code where your random numbers are generated do you **even mention** `numarray`?

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue is values are not setting to the array,

Please find below working code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num1=0, num2=0, num3=0, num4=0, num5=0;
        int [][] numArray = new int [5][5];
        int average =0, totalRow=0;
        int highestVal=0, lowestVal=0;

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
          for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
          {
            num5 = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
            numArray[row][col] = num5;
          }
        }

        //Sum all values    
        int total;
        total =0;
        System.out.println(numArray.length);
        for (int row = 0; row < numArray.length; row++)
        {
          for (int col = 0; col < numArray[row].length; col++)
          {
            total = total + numArray[row][col];
            System.out.println("Row : " + row + "/Col : " + col);
            System.out.println("Total : " + total + "/value : " + numArray[row][col]);
          }
        }

        System.out.println("The total is " + total);

    }
```

Comment: Would have been much better to let the poster work this out themselves. They would have learned something other than how to copy/paste someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

Your random number generator isn't storing the values in the array, so your program isn't adding anything.

Personally, this is my more straightforward approach:

1. Use a nested-for-loop and loop through `array[i][j] = Math.random()` function
2. Create a (sum) variable and initialize to 0.
3. Use another nested-for-loop and do: `sum += array[i][j]`